# I dont quite understand inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm doing a problem in a aops prealgebra, and I don’t  quite understand inequality.

I'm trying to find the greatest number of acute angles a quadrilateral can have

Let $n$ = number of acute angles.

- `sum of acute angles` $< 90n^{\circ}$
- `sum of remaining angles` $< 360(4-n)^{\circ}$
- $360^{\circ} < 90n^{\circ} + 360(4-n)^{\circ}$

so the inequality is just saying `sum of all angles` < `max number the sum can go`

- but even if I had $360^{\circ} < 1000000n$ the inequility would still be true

  - since `360` is always less than a much larger number

my problem is that I dont really understand the logic part in this problem

Also I really want to know is that, how can I plug in a range for algebra, like

- $360 = (1^{\circ}$ to $89^{\circ})n + (90^{\circ}$ to $359^{\circ})(4-n)$
- since sum of all angles of a quadrilateral should be sum up to `exactly 360` right? so isn't equation would make more sense?

please give me some advice, thank u

Comment: ? A quadrilateral only has 4 angles.

Comment: @coffeemath what do u mean?

Comment: vid: You said "max number of acute angles a quadrilateral can have," but that makes no sense since every quadrilateral has four angles.

Comment: @coffeemath What I was trying to say was, the greatest possible amount of acute angles an quadrilateral can have

Comment: What do you mean by "amount"? Apparently you don't mean the *number* of angles. If you mean the sum of the angle measures, that sum is 360 no matter what. If you mean what's the greatest measure of a single angle, you know that an angle *inside* of a convex quadrangle could be anything less than 180. [It couldn't be 180 or else the quadrangle would really be a triangle. The wording on the rest of what you mention is not clear to me. That is, I can't see what you're trying to do.

Comment: @coffeemath I meant the number of acute angles

Comment: "Sum of acute angles $\le 89n^{\circ}$" Incorrect. You can take $89.5^{\circ}$ as angle measures as well. What you should instead write, is the strict inequality $\to$ sum of acute angles $\lt 90n^{\circ}$. Similarly for sum of remaining angles as well.

Comment: @Cathedral True, I didn't think of that. Thank u for pointing out

Comment: You have already reached an inequality... just rearrange to solve for the range of $n$. To be specific, you should arrive at $n<4$. This coupled with the fact that $n$ can only be a natural number $\implies n=3$

Comment: [Choosing a good title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144) is also an important part of [asking a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/42969)

Comment: @vidProli I now know what you asked. [Hersh already answered it.]

Comment: @coffeemath thank u for pointing out my mistake as well :)

Comment: "You have already reached an inequality... just rearrange to solve for the range of n. To be specific, you should arrive at n<4. This coupled with the fact that n can only be a natural number ⟹n=3"  This shows you that $n$ must be less than $4$ but it doesn't show you that $n = 3$ is necessarily possible.  (It obviously *is* but an inequality is an upper bound.  There's nothing to indicate it is the *least* upper bound.)

Comment: @fleablood That is definitely true, however, I don't think there exists any other condition limiting $n$. For example, for a $m$ sided polygon, we can use a similar process to arrive at $n<\frac{2m+4}{3}$. This *does* hold for all $m$ up till $10$ (I did not check beyond that)

Comment: "however, I don't think there exists any other condition limiting n" No, there isn't. But I think this inequality is too loose and not the best argument. The avg angle of a quad is $90$. An acute angle is less than $90$. So if we have $n$ acute angles $<90$ we can measure their angles as $90-a_1, ...,90 -a_n$ where $0< a_k< 90$.  The remaining $4-n$ angles average or larger can be labeled  $90+b_{n+1}... 90+b_4$ where $0\le b_j$. So our only condition is $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k =\sum_{j=n+1}^4 b_j; b_j\ge 0; 0<a_k< 90$. That's our *only* condition so clearly we can have $n=3$ and $b_4=a_1+a_2+a_3$.

Comment: The *intutive* thing is that the acute angles can be and *close* to $90$ as we like.  Thus the sum of the angles may be as close to $90n$ as we like.  The requirment that the other angles sum to an number $S$  so that $(4-n)90 < S < (4-n)360$ is of no concern....Okay formally We require that the sum of the acute angles be $K$ we have $0 < K<90n$ and $(4-n)90< 360-K < (4-n)360$. With those restriction we reduce to $n< 4$ and $1-\frac K{360} < 4-n < 4- \frac K{90}$.  With those being the *only* restriction taking $K$ small enough, $n=3$ is certainly possible.

Comment: Logical part: We know that sum must be less than this value, then we need to find which $n$ make this inequality true. $$360^{\circ} < n\cdot 90^{\circ} + (4-n)\cdot 360^{\circ}$$
Let expand $$360^\circ<1440^\circ-n\cdot 270^\circ$$
Then $$0<1080^\circ-n\cdot 270^\circ$$
Then $$n<\frac{1080}{270}=4$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite understand your approach, but I will share my solution of the question, "Find the max number of acute angles a quadrilateral can have".

Let the angles of the quadrilateral be $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$.

Then we know that $\alpha + \beta + \gamma + \delta = 360^\circ.\tag{i}$

And yes, the sum is $exactly$ $360 ^\circ$.

Now, we know that an acute angle is always $<90^\circ$

Suppose all angles were acute. Then we would have

$\alpha + \beta + \gamma + \delta < 90^\circ \cdot 4$

$\alpha + \beta + \gamma + \delta < 360^\circ$

But that is a contradiction to (i).

Therefore, we cannot have all four angles being acute.

The next largest number, i.e., the predecessor of 4, is 3.

So consider that three angles are acute.

WLOG, we can assume that the three acute angles are $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$.

Therefore we get that

$\alpha + \beta + \gamma < 90^\circ \cdot 3$

$\alpha + \beta + \gamma < 270^\circ$.

Using (i), we get that

$270^\circ + \delta > 360^\circ$.

Subtracting $270^\circ$ from both sides of the inequality, we get

$\delta > 90^\circ$.

This condition is certainly attainable in a quadrilateral.

Therefore, the maximum number of acute angles in a quadrilateral is 3.

For example, let $\alpha = 80^\circ, \beta = 70^\circ , \gamma = 60^\circ$

By (i), we get that $\delta = 150^\circ$

This forms a completely appropriate quadrilateral.

Comment: Maybe good would be an actual example where three angles are acute.

Comment: One could take any arbitrary example as long as $\alpha + \beta + \gamma > 180^\circ$. This is any larger value would lead to a concave quadrilateral, as you mentioned. Anyways for the sake of clarification I shall add an example.

Comment: thx for your help :)